# JavaScript – Security overwriting variable by user

Tags: javascript, variables, overwrite

I have a variable in JavaScript:

```
var userIp = '192.168.0.1';
```

However, user can open browser console and overwrite it:

```
userIp = '123.45.127.21';
```

How I can lock this variable, to user can't change it value? Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How I can lock this variable, to user can't change it value? Is it possible?

No, it isn't. You can make it harder by making the variable not a global, but it's still not remotely hard.

Client-side code is completely and totally insecure. Users can change values of variables, modify code, completely *replace* the code, etc. They can also manipulate the page contents. Anything the client side sends to the server may be spoofed, and so the server has to treat everything it receives as potentially-compromised.